# Can't Select Records from a database table with grouping using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to Select an SQL table and grouping columns using Linq to SQL, Entities, or Object (I don't really know what.) I'm a bit new to Linq and could use some help. The code structure is straight-forward in my view. When I don't add in the GroupBy method, it works fine. JT_Temp is an entity model by the way. When I run my code below, it goes to the exception:

The entity or complex type 'JT_Temp' cannot be constructed in LINQ to Entities query.

I have tried [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/257/entity-framework-6-recipe-grouping-by-year-and-month) and various stackoverflow solutions but they don't seem to solve and apply to my case.

Here is my current code:

```
//Goal:
 //SELECT EnvelopeCode, Branch_COA, AQ_COA, AQ_Branch, SUM(Amount), AQ_PostStatus FROM JT_Temp
            //GROUP BY EnvelopeCode, Branch_COA, AQ_COA, AQ_Branch, AQ_PostStatus

//var csvFilteredRecord = Context.JT_Temp.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM JT_Temp").ToList<JT_Temp>(); 
// GROUP BY -- No go; Manual SELECT -- No go;

            try
            {


                var csvFilteredRecord = (
                    from c in Context.JT_Temp
                    group c by new
                    {
                        c.EnvelopeCode,
                        c.Branch_COA,
                        c.AQ_COA,
                        c.AQ_Branch,
                        c.AQ_PostStatus
                    } into i
                    select new JT_Temp
                    {
                        EnvelopeCode = i.Key.EnvelopeCode,
                        Branch_COA = i.Key.Branch_COA,
                        AQ_COA = i.Key.AQ_COA,
                        AQ_Branch = i.Key.AQ_Branch,
                        //TO-DO SUM(Amount),
                        AQ_PostStatus = i.Key.AQ_PostStatus
                    }).ToList();

                foreach (var Record in csvFilteredRecord)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                            Record.EnvelopeCode
                            + Record.Branch_COA
                            + Record.AQ_COA
                            //+ Record.Amount
                            + Record.AQ_PostStatus
                        );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---------- " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

Comment: have you looked at any of the linq examples on msdn [C# MSDN Linq GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't project into JT_Temp.  Just use an anonymous object.  Also, no reason to make it a list, so I removed the `.ToList()`
Query syntax:

```
var csvFilteredRecord = (
                from c in Context.JT_Temp
                group c by new
                {
                    c.EnvelopeCode,
                    c.Branch_COA,
                    c.AQ_COA,
                    c.AQ_Branch,
                    c.AQ_PostStatus
                } into i
                select new 
                {
                    EnvelopeCode = i.Key.EnvelopeCode,
                    Branch_COA = i.Key.Branch_COA,
                    AQ_COA = i.Key.AQ_COA,
                    AQ_Branch = i.Key.AQ_Branch,
                    //TO-DO SUM(Amount),
                    AQ_PostStatus = i.Key.AQ_PostStatus
                });
```

Method syntax:

```
var csvFilteredRecord = Context.JT_Temp.GroupBy(k=> new
  {
    c.EnvelopeCode,
    c.Branch_COA,
    c.AQ_COA,
    c.AQ_Branch,
    c.AQ_PostStatus
  },
  v=>v.Amount,
  (k,v)=>new {
    k.EnvelopeCode,
    k.Branch_COA,
    k.AQ_COA,
    k.AQ_Branch,
    k.AQ_PostStatus
    Amount=v.Sum()
  });
foreach (var Record in csvFilteredRecord)
{
  Console.WriteLine(
    Record.EnvelopeCode
    + Record.Branch_COA
    + Record.AQ_COA
    + Record.Amount
    + Record.AQ_PostStatus
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert McKee. This works. Thanks to methodman as well. I'll read about the grouping from there.